# ThingsDB timezone not working as expected

Tags: database, timezone

I want to use a *datetime* with a specific timezone but ThingsDB doesn't seem to recognise the zone. No error is returned, but the output is not what I expect.

This occurs even with a simple code example:

```
datetime('2020-12-10T16:08:24Z').to('Europe/Kyiv');
```

I would expect the above to return:

```
"2020-12-10T18:08:24+0200"
```

Instead, I get the following result:

```
"2020-12-10T16:08:24+0000"
```

I'm using ThingsDB v1.4.7 which is the latest version at this moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your `tzdata` package is not the latest. If you have the same problem with other time-zones then the package might not be installed at all.

To install the package on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install tzdata
```

On Alpine linux:

```
sudo apk add tzdata
```

Comment: I was indeed missing the `tzdata` package, thanks for the swift reply.